# How to understand that each random variable $X_t$ of a random process is defined on the same probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

According to the definition of random process, for a random process$\{X_t,t\in T\}$ each $X_t$ is defined on the same probability space $\{ \Omega,F,P\}$.
Consider the process of rolling a six-sided dice to get accumulated points, we use $X_n$ represents the point obtained from the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ roll of dice, $X_n$ represents the cumulative points of the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ roll of the dice. Obviously, the sample space of $X_1$, denoted as $\Omega_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$,and the sample space of $X_2$, denoted as $\Omega_2=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$ and so on,then it can be concluded that the sample space corresponding to each $X_t$ is different. What is the problem with my understanding?

Comment: If the sample spaces are different, then computations like $X_1+X_2$ do not make sense.  But of course adding your outcomes from rolling a die does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In resolving your confusion, you need to understand two points:

1. The sample space is not determined by a single random variable. Rather, it is determined by the random experiment you are considering. To be more specific, the sample space must be ample enough to host all the possible simultaneously-observed data. (For example, if your experiment consists of $10$ coin tossing, your sample space must be large enough to have at least $2^{10}$ different samples, each representing a possible list of $10$ successive outcomes.)
2. You should not confuse the sample space with the *support* of a distribution (which is roughly the set of all possible values of a random variable having that distribution). For example, if $X$ denotes the outcome of rolling a fair six-sided die, then

   - the support of the distribution of $X$ is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but
   - there are a plethora of probability spaces you can use to model this experiment, and in particular, the sample space hosting $X$ need not be the set $\{1, \ldots, 6\}$.

Now, returning to OP's example, let me provide two possible choices of probability spaces and $X_n$'s that can model the random experiment of rolling a six-sided fair die indefinitely and independently:

> **Example 1.** Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, and endow the probability measure $\mathbf{P}$ that is uniquely characterized by the condition
> $$ \mathbf{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : (\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n) \in A \}) = \frac{|A|}{6^n} $$
> for each $n\geq 1$ and $A\subseteq\{1,\ldots,6\}^n$. Then let
> $$X_n(\omega) = \omega_n.$$
> This choice is often referred to as a *canonical process*.

> **Example 2.** Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$, and let $\mathbf{P}$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$. Then let
> $$ X_n(\omega) = 1 + [\text{$n$th digit after the radix point in the $6$-ary expansion of $\omega$}] $$
> It can be proved that $X_n$'s are i.i.d. with the uniform distribution on $\{1,\ldots,6\}$.

Answer (score 0):

We should consider $\Omega$ being the space of (infinite) sequences in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, consider the events $E$ formed by sequences-that-begin-with-any-concrete-subsequence-of-$n$-terms for any $n$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them, and the probability $\rm P$ such that for any such event we have ${\rm P}(E) = 1/6^n$.

Then, for every natural $k$, the value of $X_k(\omega)$ for any sequence $\omega$ is the sum of the first $k$ terms of $\omega$.

I see it this way: there is nothing wrong with your understanding, in fact I think it is an obligatory question when dealing with sequences of independent variables or random processes, but it is generally overlooked... Only once you see the full explanation in several examples you can safely get used to "forget about the sample space", being confident that everything can be solidly stated anyway.

Anyway, I would like to know the opinion of experts in Statistics and Probability if they have a different point of view.